# JavaScript Object array not fetching when the value string has spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, shopping-cart

[This is the jsFiddle of my code](https://jsfiddle.net/qscrypw3/)Now I'm trying to make a cart item increment when I press the plus button and also decrement too. It works fine for single text item name like.."Chicken" but It doesn't work when the Item name has space in it like..."chicken and chips". This is the script code responsible for adding and substracting items already in the cart.

```js
  // Add to cart
  obj.addItemToCart = function(name, price, count) {
    for(var item in cart) {
      if(cart[item].name === name) {
        cart[item].count ++;
        saveCart();
        return;
      }
    }
    var item = new Item(name, price, count);
    cart.push(item);
    saveCart();
  }

  // Remove item from cart
  obj.removeItemFromCart = function(name) {
      for(var item in cart) {
        if(cart[item].name === name) {
          cart[item].count --;
          if(cart[item].count === 0) {
            cart.splice(item, 1);
          }
          break;
        }
    }
    saveCart();
  }
```

This is the button event function that makes the item increment and decrement

```js
// -1
$('.show-cart').on("click", ".minus-item", function(event) {
  var name = $(this).data('name')
  shoppingCart.removeItemFromCart(name);
  displayCart();
  iconCart();
})
// +1
$('.show-cart').on("click", ".plus-item", function(event) {
  var name = $(this).data('name')
  shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name);
  displayCart();
  iconCart();
})
```

This is the html button that adds the item using data attributes

```html
<button data-name="Pepper Soup" data-price="1.22" data-count="1" class="add-to-cart btn btn-primary">Add to cart</button>
```

This is the error I get in the browser console...

The specified value "undefined" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

Comment: can you share a fiddle where the error can be recreated. looks correct.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qscrypw3/

Comment: as you can see the data-name attribute is incorrectly set

Comment: How??, This is not the first time i have use words that have spacings in my data attribute values... Please tell me where, so that i can correct it. Thanks.

Comment: https://imgur.com/QjcHjiX

Comment: Oooh! Please how can i fix that??

Comment: Infact it looks like it was the space i gave to the data attribute value, caused this

Comment: yeah. You could use template strings to create the text to prevent the error

Comment: I have updated the answer. Do check and accept the answer if it solves your issue

Comment: SOLVED!!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/wbotk4ue/

Replacing the `""` with template strings `` solves the issue.
The problem was with spaces in data-name

Comment: and if  you want to keep the `""` you can write `"Pepper&nbsp;Soup"`

Comment: he cannot hardcode that into the data-name, since the values are dynamic

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
I solved it by adding single quotes outside the double quotes containing the array value i.e data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "' to the increment button and decrement button

```js
function displayCart() {
  var cartArray = shoppingCart.listCart();
  var shipping = 120;
  var output = "";
  for(var i in cartArray) {
    output += "<tr>"
      + "<td>" + cartArray[i].name + "</td>" 
      + "<td>(" + cartArray[i].price + ")</td>"
      + "<td><div class='input-group'><button class='minus-item input-group-addon btn btn-primary' data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "'>-</button>"
      + "<input type='number' class='item-count form-control' data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "' value='" + cartArray[i].count + "'>"
      + "<button class='plus-item btn btn-primary input-group-addon' data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "'>+</button></div></td>"
      + "<td><button class='delete-item btn btn-danger' data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "'>X</button></td>"
      + " = " 
      + "<td>" + cartArray[i].total + "</td>" 
      +  "</tr>";
  }
  $('.show-cart').html(output);
  $('.PandD').html(shipping)
  $('.total-cart').html(shoppingCart.totalCart() + shipping);
  $('.total-count').html(shoppingCart.totalCount());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution could be fine

```
value.replace(/ /g, '%25');
```

Comment: It didn't work... please check out my jsfiddle to understand what i mean  https://jsfiddle.net/qscrypw3/